# Cannot use MongoClient after close

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I've updated the pymongo and mongoengine packages, which are now 4.6.0 and 0.27.0, respectively.

After upgrading it On my Windows machine, I am trying to run celery tasks. In that celery task I have written multiple function and in which I am closing client once that particular function runs successfully, then it is calling another function which has mango client but this providing me given error:

raise InvalidOperation("Cannot use MongoClient after close")
pymongo.errors.InvalidOperation: Cannot use MongoClient after close

Code:
I am creating client and closing it in given way.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
mongo_client = MongoClient(host=host,
                         port=int(port),
                         username=username,
                         password=password,
                         authSource=authSource_db,
                         maxPoolSize=15,
                         MaxIdleTimeMS=120000
                        )
mongo_client.close()
```

Comment: Thats how its supposed to work; https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient.close  ..

Comment: Dont close the database connection. Open it when your program starts, and close it when it exits/is shut down. Never understood why so many people make this mistake. Need a database connection? Open it and keep it open...

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because celery is asynchronous. So the order in which the tasks are executed is not determined. In this case, one of the tasks needs the client but another task which maybe defined after the previous task is completed and you have closed the client.

```
with MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/') as client:
    # your code here
```

This will automatically close the connection once the tasks are completed.

Comment: So means above code which you mentioned, I have to add wherever I am opening mongo-client, right?

Comment: You can create the tasks inside the block, and pass them with the mongo client. You don't need to close them manually, they will automatically get closed once the tasks are completed.

Comment: Okay,Thanks. But how can we ensure that the client is closed after completing all tasks?

Comment: Yes, we can ensure that. The "with" statement in Python works, it calls the __enter__ function of the object class passed and the __exit__ function once it has done operating. Check this out for more ref: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/with-statement-in-python/